# Is it possible to add a Function/method to an IQueryable and Web-api to be able to use it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, breeze, varbinary

I have a `varbinary` column in SQL Server which becomes a `byte[]` in my entity (EF). This column is called `rptext` and thus contains text. I use BreezeJS in my frontend to collect and search data.

The problem is when I use the JS predicate

```
new breeze.Predicate('rptext', breeze.FilterQueryOp.Contains, 'sometext')
```

the backend returns this error:

> Error retrieving data.No function signature for the function with name 'substringof' matches the specified arguments. The function signatures considered are: substringof(Edm.String Nullable=true, Edm.String Nullable=true).

What should I do to be able to search my column `rptext` for some given text?

**UPDATE**
So the backend is web api. Web-api is returning the message above. The error is made at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.FunctionCallBinder.MatchSignatureToBuiltInFunction

So now my question is, is it possible to add such a function to my IQueryable? Keep in mind that it would need Microsoft to find that function in an assembly I made.

Also what would it need to look like?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "This field is called "rptext" and thus contains text." I'm not sure how you make the connection between an arbitrary field name and it's content. As far as your program knows, this is a large binary object. It's a bunch of bytes. If you think it's text and you want text mechanisms to work, why not use the proper datatype from the beginning?

Comment: I know it is text. We are making a cloud platform for an existing application so I cannot change the datatype...

Comment: How do you know this bunch of bytes is text? Can you convert it to text (codepage or utf-?) in your EF object?

Comment: It is specified in the existing application; Yes converting to UTF-8 gives me readable text.